# Is it possible to save extra data in the node object of a forced layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a forced layout graph using the d3 library, and I'm using it to visualize graph data.

I would like to show a human-readable label over the node, and then when clicked, query for graph-connected properties of that node (and the node itself has a `resource uri` that I would like to have stored in the data per node).

is it possible to store that extra key/val in the node object? if not, how would you go about solving that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally possible, and often desirable.

The force layout is initialized with a series of nodes (array of objects). Some params are expected to be present in those nodes (like `weight` or `fixed`) and other params are applied to those nodes by the force layout (like `x`, `y`, `px`, `py`). Any other params that you hang on those objects won't break anything and, more importantly, the force layout will not strip them out; they're persisted and are available to you when you render the layout, which is convenient and useful.

In fact, the array of objects you pass to the force layout can be an array of instances of whatever you're using to fetch and store the data (e.g. Backbone models). If doing so, there is a risk that you'd run into name collision. Like, if your model has a method called `x()`, and you pass that model into the force layout, then the layout would overwrite it with the computed `x` position. So it may be wiser to instead link to the associated model via a property of the node, but it's not inherently required.

**UPDATE**

For an example of how nodes can have extra key/val pairs that are unrelated to what the force layout works with, see [mbostock's Les Misérables visualization](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). Specifically, see how `d.group`, which is part of the loaded json, is used to determine the node color when rendered, but doesn't have any bearing on the behavior of the nodes. That would be equivalent to what you're asking to do for showing a human readable label.

Now, if you want to integrate with instances of some class, eg `Backbone.Model`s, you could do something like this (drawing on the Les Misérables example linked to above):

```
d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  var models = graph.nodes.map(function(nodeJson) {
    return new Backbone.Model(nodeJson)
  });

  force
    .nodes(models)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();
});
```

Since now these are Backbone models, you have to use `get()` for properties. So, when rendering the layout, instead of `d.group`, it would be

```
// d is a Backbone model now
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.get('group')); })
```

As I cautioned previously, you have to keep in mind that the force layout knows nothing about these being instances of Backbone models or whatnot. So internally it's not going to call something like `node.set('x', ...)` when it's computing node positions. It will, as before run `node.x = ...`, so you'll now have Backbone models that also have `x`, `y` properties applied to it by the force layout. If for some reason your model extends a Backbone model, and adds a method to it called `x: function() { ... }`, that method will get overridden (with the `x` position value) by the layout. So you have to be mindful of it, and if you need to work around it, then don't use Backbone models for nodes. Instead, use generic objects, as mbostock's example does, and store associated instances of your models on the nodes. Like

```
d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  graph.nodes.forEach(function(nodeJson) {
    bbModel = new Backbone.Model(nodeJson);
    nodeJson.model = bbModel
  });

  force
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();
});
```

Now rendering looks like this:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.bbModel.get('group')); })
```

Comment: thanks for that. is there any code that you can show me or refer me to that shows a force layout using an array of instances?

Comment: I don't know of examples that use instances of something other than generic objects, since the typical d3 examples don't incorporate other frameworks.

Comment: ok, so, then can you write a small snippet of code to demonstrate what you're saying can be done?

Comment: @Kristian Answer modified with further explanation